# PDO exception after changing the slider configuration

Tags: magento-2.1, php-pdo

I'm not a Magento developer but when a client asked me to change the slider. I changed and it was an easy option. After changing, I flushed the cache, and the site showing an error msg like PDO exception as shown below

PDOException: **SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused** in /var/www/html/purpledew/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/purpledew/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(128): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'AccelrayPurple@...', Array) #1 /var/www/html/purpledew/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #2 ...

Comment: Please try once restarting the MySQL service such as **sudo systemctl restart mysql.service** and Please check log files from **{magento root directory}/var/log**

Answer (score 0):

Connection needs to go to port 8889. The reason you are getting this error is because your connection is going to port 8888 and hence the error shows. Do this:

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;port=8889;dbname=AppDatabase", $username, $password);

You may still see the error but nonetheless the connection would pass.